# OWD settings for public site

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites, sharing, owd

We have a public site for a custom object record creation, which also links to Account.

However our Account OWD model is complicated and needs to be in Private mode. 
It seems public site requires this to be a Publicly accessible, so what are our options?

Is it possible to restrict access to Accounts per record-types even with OWD setting being Public?
Or a way to work around the requirement of needing the Account to be public for a site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OWD says Account Sobject is `Private`, it means that only owner of the Account records or the user above the hierarchy of Account owner can view the Account only.

If those site user comes above the Account owner hierarchy they will be able to view the account other wise you will need apply `Manual Sharing`.

It can be [Criteria based](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_sharing_cbs_about.htm) like if Account.RecordType = 'specific name' share it with site user.

Read about [Manual sharing here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=granting_access_to_records.htm&language=en&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F&type=0)